# Generifying method operations in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a method that does some operations on the collection that gets passed to it. This method will be called by different other methods with a different type, but the logic contained in the method will be the same throught. It is just the types that change.

```
  private def operateMethod[T](newSeq: Seq[T, Double], oldSeq: Seq[T, Double]): Seq[T, Double] = {
    val newSeqMap = newSeq.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.foldLeft(0.0)((total, current) => total + current._2))
  }
```

But the compiler seems not to be happy with accessing the type values ._1 and ._2. How to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sequence of `Tuple2[T, Double]` is a `Seq[(T, Double)]`, not `Seq[T, Double]`:

```
private def operateMethod[T](newSeq: Seq[(T, Double)], oldSeq: Seq[(T, Double])): Seq[(T, Double)] = { ... }
```